# Collision checking failed

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, collision-detection, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am using ROS Kinetic with Ubuntu 16.04. I tried the moveit tutorials given [here](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/move_group_interface/move_group_interface_tutorial.html) with my own 7 dof manipulator.
After getting the collision object in the environment, I tried some random pose planning through Rviz gui and in one of the plans the robot is shown colliding with the collision object. I am posting the pic [here](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/1562042800260404.png)Can someone tell me why it is happening ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327368/collision-checking-failed/) by [Pulkit123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28301/pulkit123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2019-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you just downloaded the franka_ros repository, then you should have these newer bigger collision volumes. In RViz you can check them if you click on Motion Planning -> Scene Robot -> Show Robot Collision. You will probably see this red "cushion" around the arm, which is in collision with the collision object you set up in the scene or will be in collision in the end pose you set out to go to.

Move the collision object/change the pose and all should be fine.

---

Originally posted by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) with karma: 589 on 2019-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pulkit123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28301/pulkit123/) on 2019-07-09**:
I tried it, but still robot does collide with the object and this time I deliberately made it to collide with the collision object as part of path planning. To my surprise, the trajectory was executed

**Comment by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) on 2019-07-09**:
Could you edit the main post with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It could be many things, but seeing what you're doing always helps.

**Comment by [Pulkit123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28301/pulkit123/) on 2019-07-10**:
you can check [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/1547)